# in Mvc View getting error result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my view I have passed a view Model why I am getting the 
Error

> result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once

Can anyone please help me on this.

Here is my View

```
@model App.ViewModels.ViewTeamList
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            @if (Model.TeamList.Count() > 0)
            {

                <div class="table-responsive">
                    @{
                var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.TeamList.ToList(), defaultSort: "TeamName", canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10);
                    }
                    @grid.WebGridSelectAll(

                            headerStyle: "gridHeader",
                            tableStyle: "table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin",
                            checkBoxValue: "TeamId",
                            columns: new[]{
                                grid.Column("TeamName",format: @<a href="#" class="details" data-id="@item.TeamId">@item.TeamName</a>,header: Html.CustomText("lblCTTeamName", "Team Name")),
                                grid.Column("Description",format: @<a href="#" class="details" data-id="@item.TeamId">@item.Description</a>, header: Html.CustomText("lblDescription", "Description"), canSort: false),
                                grid.Column("UserCount",format: @<a href="#" class="details" data-id="@item.TeamId">@item.UserCount</a>, header: Html.CustomText("lblCTUserCount", "# of User(s)"))
                            }
                             )
                </div>
                }
          else
        {
        <div>No Record Found</div>
        }
        </div>
    </div>
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewTeamList
    {
        public IEnumerable<TeamList> TeamList;
        public Team Team { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SearchTeamName { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: I'm tempted to say you don't need `ToList()` on `Model.TeamList.ToList()`

Comment: At which line do you get this error?

Comment: var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.TeamList.ToList(), defaultSort: "TeamName", canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10);

Comment: it is working fine, but when i am using @if (Model.TeamList.Count() > 0) then i am getting that error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TeamList` is an `IEnumerable`. An enumerable differs from something like a list in that its data structure is set up to pop items from the stack. Once an item has been popped it's essentially disposed, meaning you can only run through the items once.

Here, you're doing this by calling `.Count()`. In order to get a count from an enumerable, the items have to be iterated over, which effectively uses up your enumeration. Then, when you try to run it through `WebGrid`, you get that error. You either need to cast `TeamList` to a list and store the result:

```
@{ var teamList = Model.TeamList.ToList(); }
@if (teamList.Count() > 0)
{
    ...
```

Or, probably better, just change the type of the property on your view model:

```
public List<TeamList> TeamList { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the Idea. with some modification now it's working.